# Passing a value to AngularJS click event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Suppose I have a table like this:

```
<tbody>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="object in objects">
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="{{object.id}}" data-ng-checked="object.checked" data-ng-mode="object.checked"/></td>
        <td>{{object.name}}</td>
        <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="objectEdit()">Edit</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">View</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

What is the *right* way to have `objectEdit` notified which entry in `objects` is being referenced here?

Sorry, AngularJS newb.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit:** created a demo on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oriPDP4sRDVoLy9AEWlz?p=preview).

You can use the expected behaviour like:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="objectEdit(object)">Edit</a>
```

then in the scope have this method

```
$scope.objectEdit = function(item){
}
```

**Or**

without passing the object in the click function

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="objectEdit()">Edit</a>
```

and in the scope:

```
$scope.objectEdit = function(){
   this.item // access selected item
}
```

The property "item" on the called function context is always available, even if you pass the element to the function, so I would recommend not passing the object as parameter it is less verbose I guess.

Comment: you will really have `$scope.objectEdit`, not just method in scope.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass it into the function:

```
ng-click="objectEdit(object)"
```

To expand from my original answer (sorry was short because it was answered on my mobile), you can pass into your function the object in a loop.  Also, and sometimes it makes more sense especially if you have an array, to pass in the index when you are looping over it in an `ng-repeat`:

```
ng-click="objectEdit($index)"
```

This allows us to splice or edit the element in the array:

```
$scope.objectEdit = function(i) {
   $scope.objects.splice(i,1);  // if we want to remove it in a delete function
   $scope.objects[i].name = 'new name';
};
```